# jQuery val() can't get value from input

Tags: jquery, html, ios, ajax

I have test for **Desktop** Browser, such as **Chrome**, **Firefox**, and Safari on **Macbook**.

They all work fine, but only get empty value on iOS devices
Test on iPhone5 8.1.2
Html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Control Panel</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="admin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="change_type" name="change_type" hidden="hidden" value="" />
    <div class="type-select">
        <div class="radio">
            <input id="simple_captcha" name="captcha_select" type="radio" value="simple_captcha" />
            <label for="simple_captcha" class="select-label radio-label">Simple Captcha</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <input id="svg_captcha" name="captcha_select" type="radio" value="svg_captcha" />
            <label for="svg_captcha" class="select-label radio-label">SVG Captcha</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="type.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

admin.js (load in head tag):

```
function detectSetting(settingType, mod) {
    var setting_type = $('#change_type').attr('value');
    var data = {};
    data['settingType'] = setting_type;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin.php?mod='+mod,
        data: data,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#show-setting').html(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

type.js (load in body tag):

```
    var mod = 'type';
    $('.type-select>.radio input').change(function() {
        detectSetting('show_captcha_type', mod);
    });

    $('.type-select>.radio').click(function(event) {
        $('#change_type').attr('value', event.target.id);
    });
```

I have use Safari Debug to see the result on console,
only on iOS, the `$('#change_type').attr('value');` script will get empty, even I use Safari on Mac, it worked fine, so I think the problem is on iOS...

Edit: the script `$('#change_type').attr('value', event.target.id);` worked fine, it change the value attribute of `#change_type` successfully, it just can't read the value of it on iOS

Comment: Try like: var setting_type = $('#change_type').val();

Comment: @slon Tried, but still can't get the value.. Now I can only get the value from `$('.type-select>.radio').click` ....